# Open source or free financial analysis programs/libraries

Tags: statistics, finance

I'm looking for something containing similar functions to Matlab’s financial and financial derivatives toolbox but don’t have the cash to spend on matlab. I would appreciate any info on free or open source libraries or programs that will let me easily calculate interest rates, risk etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [JQuantLib](http://www.jquantlib.org/index.php/Main_Page) or [QuantLib](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml)?

Comment: Octave doesn't do everything I want but quandlib should. I'm looking at using swig to allow me to call Quandlib functions from octave so I get the ability to deal with large datasets and run calculations with out needing to write a custom program to use Quantlib.

Answer (score 2):

How about the [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) financial functions?

http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Financial-Functions.html#Financial-Functions

I'm not familiar with the Matlab toolbox, so you'll have to judge for yourself.

> GNU Octave is a high-level language,
>   primarily intended for numerical
>   computations. It provides a convenient
>   command line interface for solving
>   linear and nonlinear problems
>   numerically, and for performing other
>   numerical experiments using a language
>   that is mostly compatible with Matlab.
>   It may also be used as a
>   batch-oriented language.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what functions do you need? How advanced? You have some financial functions in .Net

Im sure it doesnt cover everything, but calulating interests and some other are no problem:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/daksysx3(VS.80).aspx

> Calculate depreciation. **DDB, SLN, SYD**
>
> Calculate future value.
>    **FV**
>
> Calculate interest rate.
>    **Rate**
>
> Calculate internal rate of return.
>    **IRR, MIRR**
>
> Calculate number of periods.
>    **NPer**
>
> Calculate payments.
>    **IPmt, Pmt, PPmt**
>
> Calculate present value.
>   **NPV, PV**