# There's a library for .NET that does financial calculations or implements Excel-like functions?

Tags: .net, asp.net, finance

I'm working in a ASP.NET project wich is suposed to do several financial calculantions involving potentiations, nth roots, etc. For this first operations, I can easily solve the problem using Math. But, for calculating work days - like Excel, or monthly loan payment, interest rates, etc. - like HP 12C, there is a library that implements these functions? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check out the [Excel Financial functions for .NET](https://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelFinancialFunctions/)

> This is a .NET library that provides the full set of financial functions from Excel. The main goal for the library is compatibility with Excel, by providing the same functions, with the same behaviour. Note though that this is not a wrapper over the Excel library; the functions have been re-implemented in managed code so that you do not need to have Excel installed to use this library.

The Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly in .NET 4.0 also exposes some [financial functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/287wzkdy.aspx). Even though they are ostensibly VB 4.0 keywords there is nothing stopping you from referencing them from a C# or other CLR language project (I'm assuming they are CLR-compliant).

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Webster. This library is amazing. It's almost all that I need! Now I'm looking for a library that calculates the date/time (eg. workdays) like Excel. I'm implementing for myself in .NET, but I'd feel more confortable doing it with widely used and tested functions, moreover I'm dealing with financial issues! ;)

Comment: For that you should look at Noda Time, the .Net port of Joda Time (a very popular date/time library for the Java platform). Bonus: it is spearheaded by Stack Overflow boffin Jon Skeet. http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Open source or free financial analysis programs/libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333030/open-source-or-free-financial-analysis-programs-libraries)